# How to formulate the constrained optimization problem?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-optimization, constraint-programming

I have a linear problem, which I want to maximize.

There are 4 candy boxes. For each of them, I have these facts:

1. On selling `100` candies from box `A` we earn `150` dollars.
2. On selling `400` candies from box `B` we earn `250` dollars.
3. On selling `130` candies from box `C` we earn `190` dollars.
4. On selling `10`  candies from box  `D` we earn `50` dollars.

The problem I would like to formulate is..how to maximize the dollars earned by selling the "optimal" candies more frequently? In other words, how to find the right coefficients i.e `(W)*A + (X)*B + (Y)*C + (Z)*D` which can dictate the respective frequencies (or percentage distribution) with which I should sell these candies to maximize the dollars earned?

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure I am following.  Where are the constraints?  Just sell the candies from $D$, they are $\$5$ each.  Presumably there are reasons why this is not acceptable, yes?

Comment: Thats true. Perhaps the constraints I have mentioned above are incorrect. In any way, is there a method to find the distribution based on which I can sell the candies?

Comment: If you sell 50 candies from box A, do you earn 75 dollars? Does 200 candies get you $300?

Comment: yes. 50 candies from box A gives 75. 200 candies will give 300.

Comment: You didn't mention a single constraint.  You just told us how much profit you get from each type of candy.

Comment: Maybe i need to rephrase the question. Question would be, if candies from box N make X dollars, is there a way to come up with a frequency distribution that can maximize the revenue? Like sell 25% from box A, 30% from box B .. and so on..

Comment: @lulu I modified the problem statement.

Comment: As stated, you should sell only the ones with the highest profit, obviously.  Usually in these problems there are constraints.  Something that prevents you from just doing the obvious thing.  But not here, apparently.

Comment: Selling 14% A, 67.4% B, 14.4% C and 4.2% D in a given time frame will yield the same profit from each box.